# Flutter: Amplify Datastore observe.query within GetxController giving RangeError [index] on app screen

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, aws-amplify, flutter-getx

I've configured amplify within GetxController and getting error while displaying real time data extracted from cloud to flutter app using [Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/real-time/q/platform/flutter/). I'm successfully able to print data to debug console in VSCode but getting below error when displaying data on app screen

```
RangeError [index]:  Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

[image]

Code (main.dart)

```
import 'package:amplify1new/views/todolistpage.dart';
import 'package:amplify_api/amplify_api.dart';
import 'package:amplify_datastore/amplify_datastore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Amplify Flutter Packages
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'amplifyconfiguration.dart';
import 'models/ModelProvider.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class AmplifyController extends GetxController {
  RxBool isloading = true.obs;
  RxBool isAmplifySuccessfullyConfigured = false.obs;

  // List<Todo> todoListObserve = RxList<Todo>();
  RxList<Todo> todoListObserve = <Todo>[].obs;

  // RxList<Todo> todoListObservee = <Todo>[].obs;
  // RxList<Todo> todoListObserve = <Todo>[].obs;

  RxList<Todo> todoListRead = <Todo>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    if (!Amplify.isConfigured) {
      _configureAmplify();
      isAmplifySuccessfullyConfigured.value = true;
      safePrint(
        'isAmplifySuccessfullyConfigured: ${isAmplifySuccessfullyConfigured.value}',
      );
    }
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future<void> _configureAmplify() async {
    safePrint('Is Amplify Configured: ${Amplify.isConfigured}');
    final datastorePlugin =
        AmplifyDataStore(modelProvider: ModelProvider.instance);
    final api = AmplifyAPI();

    try {
      await Amplify.addPlugins([datastorePlugin, api]);
      await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
      safePrint('Successfully configured Amplify ');
      await observeQueryy();
      await readData();
      safePrint('Is Loading Before: ${isloading.value}');
      isloading.value = false;
      safePrint('Is Loading After: ${isloading.value}');
    } catch (e) {
      safePrint('Error occured while configuring amplify: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> observeQueryy() async {
    try {
      QuerySnapshot<Todo>? todoListObserve =
          await Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery(
        Todo.classType,
      ).firstWhere(
        (element) => element.isSynced,
        orElse: null,
      );

      safePrint('todoListObserve : $todoListObserve');
      safePrint('todoListObserve : ${todoListObserve.items[0].name}');
      // safePrint('todoListObserve : ${todoListObserve[0].name}');
    } on DataStoreException catch (e) {
      safePrint('Something went wrong querying posts: ${e.message}');
    }
  }

  Future<void> readData() async {
    try {
      todoListRead = RxList(
        await Amplify.DataStore.query(
          Todo.classType,
        ),
      );

      safePrint('todoListRead: $todoListRead');
      safePrint('todoListRead: ${todoListRead[0].name}');
    } on DataStoreException catch (e) {
      safePrint('Something went wrong querying posts: ${e.message}');
    }
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      initialBinding: BindingsBuilder(() {
        Get.put<AmplifyController>(AmplifyController());
      }),
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final amplifyController = Get.find<AmplifyController>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: const Text('Demo Flutter Amplify')),
      body: Obx(() => amplifyController.isloading.value
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                    'Read Data-------${amplifyController.todoListRead[0].name}'),

                // RangeError [index]:  Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
                Text(
                    'Observe Data--${amplifyController.todoListObserve[0].name}'),
              ],
            )),
    );
  }
}
```

amplifyconfiguration.dart

```
const amplifyconfig = ''' {
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "api": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsAPIPlugin": {
                "amplify1new": {
                    "endpointType": "GraphQL",
                    "endpoint": "https://bxnr5wy3xjg4xm7hw5dfz7qoya.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql",
                    "region": "us-east-1",
                    "authorizationType": "API_KEY",
                    "apiKey": "da2-hazvgkvkqjgx7dhzlids752lfy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}''';
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: amplify1new
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  # sdk: '>=3.1.0-171.0.dev <4.0.0'
  sdk: ">=2.18.0 <4.0.0"
  flutter: ">=3.3.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  amplify_flutter: ^1.0.0
  amplify_datastore: ^1.0.0-supports-only-mobile
  amplify_api: ^1.0.0
  get: ^4.6.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Debug Console VsCode outputs data from Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery
[image]

How can I make flutter app screen to show the data from remote cloud using 'Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery'?

Comment: You are initializing `todoListObserve` and `todoListRead` with empty lists, but then you are doing things like  `todoListRead[0].name`. If `todoListRead` is empty then there is no element at position `0` for which to get a name from.